# How to disconnect from the webcam using directshow?

Tags: c#, directshow.net

I used `directshow.net` with my web-cam and it worked so well. But when I closed the form and opened it again, it gives me an error in the method `SetupGraph()` because the value that come from the next code line is negative.

`hr = capGraph.RenderStream(ref cat, ref med, capFilter, null, null);`

but when I unplugged my camera, it works good the second time.

I hope it's not a big deal.

Comment: Unfamiliar with the SDK, but is there a method to close the Stream?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to call `yourMediaControl.StopWhenReady()` method and after that release all com object instances like `graph`, `source`, `grabber`, `capture graph` with [Marshal.ReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx).

> The **IMediaControl.StopWhenReady** method
>   pauses the filter graph, allowing
>   filters to queue data, and then stops
>   the filter graph.

Main thing is that each time you start webcam video you need to do all this:

1. create graph builder, filter graph, device object, grabber...
2. render stream
3. run media control
4. wait until user signals to stop the video
5. stop media control (StopWhenReady)
6. release / destroy created objects